# Extracting portions of text to a table with Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am extracting portions of text to a table.  The text is similar to the following:

`05:27 – 08:47Hrs, Rivers GT1 tripped on low gas pressure.  LHR = 10MW`.

I need to extract:

1. The Time in its column

   - e.g.: `05:27`, `08:47`
2. The text in the middle in its column

   - e.g.: `Rivers GT1 tripped on low gas pressure.`
3. The figure in MW

   - e.g.: `10`

I actually don't know how to go about it but I have the 1st and 3rd part handled with a regular expression.

`\d{2}:\d{2}` for the 1st part
`\d+(?=MW)`   for the 3rd part

I need help with the 2nd part.

Comment: Please give several pairs of sample inputs and desired outputs. Alternatively explain the logic of each of the three desired parts abstractly but more precisely. "the time" is not ery helpful when there are oviously two times. "the text" is extremely vague. Including the second time? The "-"? The ","? The "."? The "LHR ="? Is the figure always in MW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I assume that you would like to extract the following:

> Rivers GT1 tripped on low gas pressure

You can do this via the following regex:

```
(?:, )([^.]+)
```

Explanation to individual regex parts can be seen in the regex demo top right corner (link below).

In fact, you can build a single regex for all three of your cases, and then extract the necessary parts you need via groups:

```
(\d{2}:\d{2})|(?:, )([^.]+)|(\d+(?=MW))
```

[image]

So for example `\d{2}:\d{2}` will be in **Group 1**, `(?:, )([^.]+)` is **Group 2**, `\d+(?=MW)` is **Group 3**. You then fill your table with the corresponding group value.

Refer for details to [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aX7xye/2).

Comment: Thank you very much @vs97 that was helpful